# forgot my update password

Tags: updates

I have forgot my update password after a six months vacation abroad what can I do to reset it ?

My OS login works but when I download updates it asks for authentication but I can't remember the password ?

while trying to post this I got an error message asking to describe my question and what I have done to try to correct it well if I new how to correct it I would not be asking on here would I ?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot

https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password

Also, in the future, if you are the only one using your machine make your su (what you call update) password the same as your user login. The su password is the admin password. Any actions that make global changes to system will prompt for the su password.